# why the parameters of collision is difference with the visual in one link?

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

why the parameters of collision is different from the visual in one link? when visual use mesh from web model, the size of the box is not same with the collision, what influence will appear to the model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/243/why-the-parameters-of-collision-is-difference-with-the-visual-in-one-link?/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-11-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The visual has no influence on the physics engine, only the rendering side.

Collision dynamics calculation are a computationally costly operations, hence sometimes simpler geometry is sometimes selected. Simulation can then run faster, but collisions are slightly less realistic. I do not know what model your are referring, so it is hard to give a fully conclusive answer. (using a smaller size of the same simple geometry might be just an error).

Calculations are done using the collision geometry i.e.: if you have two models of balls with far smaller collision geometry they will appear to move into each other before colliding (and sink in the ground too). Try it in the simulator.

---

Originally posted by [Erik Stoltenborg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/77/erik-stoltenborg/) with karma: 86 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2012-11-20**:
thanks, Erik. more help for me.